# SassC::SyntaxError in rails assets:precompile with bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-6

I use the latest bootstrap gem and rails 6

SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Invalid CSS after "...-inverse: #fff;": expected "}", was "--$danger: #cc101d;"
        on line 3784:19 of stdin

> > --inverse: #fff;

------------------^
stdin:3784
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/sassc-2.2.0/lib/sassc/engine.rb:49:in `render'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/sassc-rails-2.1.2/lib/sassc/rails/compressor.rb:29:in`call'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/sprockets-3.7.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in`call_processor'

Comment: can you please explain more with the code or may please put Screen Shot what you are facing.

Comment: I try to deploy to heroku and on assets:precompile it breaks.

Comment: Sass syntax error problem is really hard to find. The faster way would be just revert your code with git and deploy. Repeat until succeeds. And find which commit did this error. Ever after you found the commit, it gonna be really hard to spot the problem. So you have to remove-add parts of CSS code until you find which line did break it. Any of online CSS validators wont help. The error description is useless.